# Como leer un XML de archivo soap

Tags: php, json, xml, php7, soap

Hola estoy intentando obtener el **nro de ticket** de una respuesta que esta en formato xml de tipo soap, estuve buscando alguna respesta en los articulos pero no logro dar con ninguna. Mi codigo con la que he intentado fue este:

```php
        $result = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <soap-env:Header/>
        <soap-env:Body>
            <br:sendSummaryResponse xmlns:br="http://service.sunat.gob.pe">
                <ticket>1675038109554</ticket>
            </br:sendSummaryResponse>
        </soap-env:Body>
    </soap-env:Envelope>

    $library = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
    $ns = $library->getDocNamespaces();
    $ext1 = $library->children($ns['soap-env']);
    $ext2 = $ext1->Body;
    $ext3 = $ext2->children($ns['br']);
    $ext4 = $ext3->sendSummaryResponse;
    $ext5 = $ext4->children();
    $ticket = $ext5->ticket;
    
    var_dump($ticket);
```

y como respuesta recibe NADA solo una pantalla en blanco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Casi lo logras, lo que hace falta es eliminar caracteres especiales de las etiquetas `br:sendSummaryResponse`, es decir, debes quitar esos dos puntos `:`. Eso lo puedes hacer con la siguiente línea de código:

```
$result = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $result);
```

Y en `$ext2->children();` no hace falta poner `$ns` ya que si revisas lo que contiene vas a ver que `br` no existe y por eso te retorna el error.

Ejemplo completo:

**Nota:** Puse algunos `var_dump` extra que puedes utilizar para ver lo que hace cada sección.

**Nota 2:** En la variable `$result` hay que escapar las comillas `"` para que sea interpretado como `xml`.

```
<?php
$result = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
    <soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\">
        <soap-env:Header/>
        <soap-env:Body>
            <br:sendSummaryResponse xmlns:br=\"http://service.sunat.gob.pe\">
                <ticket>1675038109554</ticket>
            </br:sendSummaryResponse>
        </soap-env:Body>
    </soap-env:Envelope>";


// Eliminamos los dos puntos y otros caracteres especiales en caso de que existan
$result = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $result);

$library = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

$ns = $library->getDocNamespaces();
//var_dump($ns);
$ext1 = $library->children($ns['soap-env']);
//var_dump($ext1);
$ext2 = $ext1->Body;
//var_dump($ext2);
$ext3 = $ext2->children();
//var_dump($ext3);
$ext4 = $ext3->brsendSummaryResponse;
//var_dump($ext4);
$ext5 = $ext4->children();
//var_dump($ext5);
$ticket = $ext5->ticket;
print($ticket);
?>
```

Esto imprime:

```
1675038109554
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, funciona perfectamente estuve dia y medio buscando respuestas.... Te agradezco :)

Comment: No hay de que, siempre es bueno intentar ver que sucede en cada línea para saber en que parte se origina el problema. Saludos!